# Python 3 Regular expression on html links

Tags: python, regex

my title may not be the most precise but I had some trouble coming up with a better one and considering it's work hours I'll go with this.

What I am trying to do is get the links from this specific page, then by using RE find specific links that are job ads with certain keywords in it.

Currently I find 2 ads but I haven't been able to get all the ads that match my keyword(in this case it's "säljare", Swedish for sales).

I would appreciate it anyone could look at my RE and say or hint towards fixing it. Thank you!:)

```
import urllib, urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://se.indeed.com/jobb?l=V%C3%A4stra+G%C3%B6talands+L%C3%A4n&start=10&pp=AAoAAAFd6hHqiAAAAAEX-kSOAQABQVlE682pK5mDD9vTZGjJhZBXQGaw6Nf2QaY"

reKey = re.compile('^<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*säljare.*)</a>')

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

dataSoup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for link in dataSoup.find_all('a'):
    linkMatch = re.match(reKey, str(link))
    if linkMatch:
        print(linkMatch)
        print(linkMatch.group(1), linkMatch.group(2))
```

Comment: Would be nice to know why my post is getting downvoted so I can improve my future overflow posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not need a regex at all. Just check, if the `title` attribute containing the job title is present in the link and then check for a list of keyword (I added *truckförare* as a second keyword).

```
import urllib, urllib.request
import re
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://se.indeed.com/jobb?l=V%C3%A4stra+G%C3%B6talands+L%C3%A4n&start=10&pp=AAoAAAFd6hHqiAAAAAEX-kSOAQABQVlE682pK5mDD9vTZGjJhZBXQGaw6Nf2QaY"

keywords = ['säljare', 'truckförare']

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

dataSoup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for link in dataSoup.find_all('a'):
    # if we do have a title attribute, check for all keywords
    # if at least one of them is present, 
    # then print the title and the href attribute
    if 'title' in link.attrs:
        title = link.attrs['title'].lower()
        for kw in keywords:
            if kw in title:
                print(title, link.attrs['href'])
```

While I personally like regexes (yes, I'm that kind of person ), most of the time you can get away with a little parsing in Python which IMHO makes the code more readable.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I will check on it more in depth when I get home. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `re` can you try `in` keyword.

```
for link in dataSoup.find_all('a'):
    if keyword in link:
        print link
```

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

`<a[^>]+href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]+title=\"((?=[^\"]*säljare[^\"]*)[^\"]+)\"`

```
<a                       // literal
[^>]+                    // 1 or more not '>'
href=\"([^\"]+)\"        // href literal then 1 or more not '"' grouped
[^>]+                    // 1 or more not '>'
title=\"                 // literal
(                        // start of group
(?=[^\"]*säljare[^\"]*)  // look ahead and match literal enclosed by 0 or more not '"'
[^\"]+                   // 1 or more not '"'
)\"                      // end of group
```

Flags: global, case insensitive

Assumes: title after href

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9HWj2/1)

Comment: This regex did not work, the result was 1 job ad.  Thanks for trying tho!